# Bulk Complete Forms

Tags: form, file-upload

I'm new to SharePoint, so not sure on the terminology.

I currently have a form that needs to have 6 data points entered and a checkbox ticked before it can be processed. I have approximately 300 data sets to enter in the form in an excel spreadsheet. Is it possible to bulk upload the spreadsheet into the form or directly into sharepoint so I don't have to manually complete each form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have SP2010 but SP2013 is the same. You can use DasheetView to use the list like excel.

[image]